# Android Studio - ¿Por que mi app a veces no envía emails?

Tags: android, android-studio, email, mail

**DESCRIPCIÓN:**

Estoy trabajando con java y descargué 3 archivos (librerias) para implementar el envío de emails por medio de mi app. Los usuarios, al registrarse, deberían recibir un mail con un código de confirmación.

**PROBLEMA:**

Algunos usuarios reciben el mail pero otros no. ¿Por qué será? ¿La versión de android del dispositivo afectará?

**CÓDIGO JAVA CON EL CUAL ENVÍO EMAILS:**

```
bt_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

View view = register.this.getCurrentFocus();
if(view != null){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
    return new PasswordAuthentication("info.doggyapp@gmail.com", "PRIVADO");
}
});

RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
task.execute();

}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        try{
            codigo = (int) (Math.random() * 9999);
            if(codigo < 1000){
                codigo = codigo + 1000;
            }

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("testfrom354@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(et_email.getText().toString().trim()));
            message.setSubject(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "app - " + getResources().getString(R.string.registro_de_usuario));
            message.setContent(getResources().getString(R.string.codigo_verificacion) + ": " + String.valueOf(codigo), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        catch(MessagingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        p.progress.dismiss();

        final Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(scroll_registro, getResources().getString(R.string.enviamos_email) + " " + et_email.getText().toString().trim(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snack.setBackgroundTint(Color.parseColor("#FFE15A"));
        snack.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        snack.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.ok),new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                snack.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snack.setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        snack.show();
    }
}
```

**LINK DE DESCARGA DE LOS 3 ARCHIVOS (LIBRERIAS EXECUTABLE JAR FILES)**

https://www.mediafire.com/file/hip0cgq399ki1cb/archivos.zip/file

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: Debes buscar en el LogCat que mensaje muestra

Comment: Ok jorge, muchas gracias!